# The data written into a file is out of order in apache beam

Tags: file, apache-beam

I am reading a Json file using TextIO in apache beam and trying to write it back into a file (Just to see what is being read). The output file data is not in the correct format

Input:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "mrscarter",
    "email_address": null,
    "phone_number": null,
    "first_name": "Beyonce",
    "last_name": "Knowles-Carter",
    "middle_name": null,
    "sex": null,
    "birthdate": "1981-09-04",
    "join_date": "2016-01-01",
    "previous_logins": 10000,
    "last_ip": "testing"
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "jayz",
    "email_address": null,
    "phone_number": null,
    "first_name": "Shawn",
    "last_name": "Carter",
    "middle_name": "Corey",
    "sex": null,
    "birthdate": "1969-12-04",
    "join_date": "2016-01-01",
    "previous_logins": 20000,
    "last_ip": null
}]
```

Output:

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "mrscarter",
    "email_address": null,
    "phone_number": null,
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "jayz",
    "email_address": null,
    "phone_number": null,
    "middle_name": null,
    "sex": null,
    "birthdate": "1981-09-04",
    "join_date": "2016-01-01",
    "middle_name": "Corey",
    "sex": null,
    "birthdate": "1969-12-04",
    "join_date": "2016-01-01",
    "previous_logins": 20000,
    "last_ip": null
}]
    "first_name": "Shawn",
    "last_name": "Carter",
    "first_name": "Beyonce",
    "last_name": "Knowles-Carter",
    "previous_logins": 10000,
    "last_ip": "testing"
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to write into a file in sequence?

**Edit**:

It is a basic pipeline that reads Json and writes it back to file.

```
PipelineOptions options = 
   PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

Schema  schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new 
      File("C:\\Users\\abc\\\\beamexample\\src\\main\\schemas\\test.avsc"));

    PCollection<String> inputJson=
           p.apply("Read JSON", TextIO.read().
                    from("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\test.json"));

    inputJson.apply(TextIO.write().withoutSharding().to("C:\\Users\\abc\\beamexample\\Output.txt"));
  p.run();
```

I don't see any other way to check whether the PCollection has the data so I am writing it back to file to check

Comment: Would be good to include the (minimal) code of your pipeline as well.

Comment: In general Apache Beam is a data flow model, where individual data flows through steps and aggregation. The order shouldn't usually matter as long as the data is processed. In particular since Apache Beam is designed for embarrassingly parallel processes. So you could for example read filenames from a text file and process them in any order. If you are processing JSON objects, it would make sense to store them as JSONL, where each line is a JSON object. What is your actual use-case?

Comment: I am trying to convert a JSON file to Avro and trying to see if the PCollection after reading the file has all the input data and  noticed that the data is not formatted. Your answer makes sense.